# what will be the higher range for maxUrlLength and maxQueryStringLength

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am getting **Remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request**. exception when i try to upload zip file to Web API hosted on remote server.

my web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="300000000" />
```

IIS displays:

- Max Querystring = 2048
- Max URL length = 4096

found that my URL exceeds this limit. googled to figure maximum value for QueryString and URLLength. But, I am not able to find constant result for this,

I tried with:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="300000000" 
             relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" 
             maxUrlLength="65536" maxQueryStringLength="2097151"/>
```

Comment: Why are you even attempting to upload a file through a URL? That's what the body is for

Comment: i am just using WebClient and the code i have used to invoke the service is var strResponse = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(webClient.UploadData((Properties.Settings.Default.WebAPIEndPoint + "/test"), "POST", bData));